# XBOX One - Microsoft Family Accounts

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, fortnite-battle-royale

I might need a little hand-holding here. I have two boys who bought an Xbox One on which they both use my Xbox/Microsoft account (I don't actually play, just used to set the console up for them) to play games (i.e. Fortnite).

I just created a Microsoft "Family" account, and created "Child" accounts for my sons, and would now like to get them set up so they can each log in to their own profile on Xbox, and play their respective games through *their* profile, and not the master "Family" profile.

How do I get this all set up so that they have their own profile (not sure about the Xbox gamertag versus the Fortnite name), and can play under the Family account and both have access to the Xbox Live subscription?

1. Can they both play under the master account and both have access to Xbox Live?
2. Can I transfer the "history" of their previous Fortnite gameplay to the oldest sons' new profile?
3. Is the Xbox gamertag the same as the Fortnite player name?

Goal:

- Master Account (dad@example.com) - Holds Xbox Live Subscription, Gamertag "Dad1" (which is the original gamertag)

  - Son 1 (son1@example.com), Gamertag "Son1", Fortnite name "Son1"
  - Son 2 (son2@example.com), Gamertag "Son2", Fortnite name "Son2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, there are, yes you correctly summarized, three things that matter and that are separate.

1. Your Microsoft account which you used with your mail (dad@example.com) and which bought the Live subscription. This account can administer the family and be used to access all the neat features of a Microsoft account. These features include OneDrive, Office 365 (if bought), Outlook Calendars, and many more. One of the benefits is also...
2. Your Gamertag. This is an alias you use across all Microsoft platforms, in the Xbox Live "universe" to track your game progress (saves are stored in the cloud on the Xbox One), your gamerscore, friends, purchase history, etc.
3. Your Fortnite name which is tied to Fortnite and has nothing to do with your Xbox.

What you want to do is, on your Xbox One, log in your son's profiles. [Here is how.](https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/add-remove-account-xbox-one) this will enable your sons to go online and, since they are part of your family, have access to your Live subscription.

As for the Fortnite account, have you linked your Fortnite account to your gamertag? If so, you can unlock them and link your Fortnite account to a new gamertag. Progress on Fortnite (in game) is tied to your Fortnite account, not your gamertag. You gamertag only holds the related achievements.